# Are programs in NASM's assembly language cross-OS

Tags: assembly, nasm

NASM is cross-OS. I wonder if that implies that programs in NASM's assembly language are also cross-OS i.e. OS-independent or OS-specific? For example, can a program in NASM's assembly language be assembled by NASM  on Linux and on Windows? Thanks.

Comment: Not a complete program that has any visible effect outside the program. Not without conditionally including bits of OS specific source code.

Comment: Yes, it can be assembled on any system where `nasm` itself can be run. Whether the output is useful on the particular system is another matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes and no. It is completely possible to write a program that runs on both Linux and Windows, but most likely it wouldn't be that useful.

Sure, you can compile any valid assembly code with NASM on both platforms and package it in a format recognized by them but *you must not have any OS specific code* in there for it to properly run.

For example, you can write a program that calculates 1000 prime numbers or synthesizes sounds to play Beethoven's 9th Symphony, but since there is no OS independent way to show that to the user or store the results anywhere, it is quite useless.

The first thing you'll run into is I/O. There is no OS independent way to do that so you need OS dependent libraries at least. And not just any libraries, since the calling conventions differ between platforms.

So even if you had, for example, the exact same C library for doing your I/O you would have to make a library that takes your single way of calling functions in assembly and transform it into the calling convention that the target OS supports.

So the practical answer is: any meaningful program will be OS dependent.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the executable formats are different, so it's unlikely you can have single binary which runs on both. But you could write very thin wrapper programs for different OSes, which load and run binary code. If you added suitable callable routines to wrapper, you could also add any desired IO etc functionality. Alternatively you could add OS detection to loaded binary code, and then do different things on different OS, but then you would have to code support for each OS into the binary, and you still need the loader, so this would be less useful.

So, same assembly will run, natively and at full speed and without any "emulation tricks", if you just provide a way to get it running.